# Request.query undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I'm trying to get the ean from this url: http://my_server.com/?ean=7038010034985

The NodeJS server handles the request like so:

```
const http = require('http')
const port = 3000

const requestHandler = async (request, response) => {

    let bar_code = request.query.ean
    bar_code = "7038010034985"

    let product = await Promise.race([
        get_info_meny_joker(bar_code, "meny.no"),
        get_info_meny_joker(bar_code, "joker.no"),
        get_info_openfoodfacts(bar_code)
    ])

    // WRITE TO DATABASE
    // database.ref('test/' + bar_code).set(product);

    response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    response.end(JSON.stringify(product))
}

const server = http.createServer(requestHandler)

server.listen(port, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.log('Error occurred', err)
  }

  console.log(`Server is listening on ${port}`)
})
```

The application crashes (request.query.ean is undefined) as soon as it reaches "let bar_code = request.query.ean". I've googled around a bit, I just don't see what I'm doing different to the examples I've found. It worked just fine earlier when I was routing the request. Any ideas?

Full error message underneath (line and character places might be off because of heavily cutting code to post here)

```
0|index    | TypeError: Cannot read property 'ean' of undefined
0|index    |     at Server.requestHandler (/home/ubuntu/kalori_app/server/index.js:32:34)
0|index    |     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
0|index    |     at Server.emit (events.js:214:7)
0|index    |     at Server.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/@pm2/io/build/main/metrics/httpMetrics.js:166:33)
0|index    |     at parserOnIncoming (_http_server.js:619:12)
0|index    |     at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:115:23)
```

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html Refer this documentation

Comment: "get the ean" What is "ean"?

Comment: @Geuis Just a random name for the parameter in the URL. It refers to bar codes, usually found on products in shops.

Comment: `request` from `http` isnt going to have a parsed query object (like express (or other middleware) generate and provide). You have to do that or use middleware

Comment: @PatrickEvans Hm, I guess I somehow used Express earlier. Oh well, guess I'll add yet another library to parse the url then.

Comment: You dont __have__ to use a library, the url is in `request.url` you could parse it yourself if you dont want to rely on external libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Node.js `url` API, it will parse everything for you:

```js
const http = require('http'),
      url  = require('url'); // Import the library
const port = 3000

const requestHandler = async (request, response) => {

    let bar_code = url.parse(request.url, true).query.ean; // Then use it

    let product = await Promise.race([
        get_info_meny_joker(bar_code, "meny.no"),
        get_info_meny_joker(bar_code, "joker.no"),
        get_info_openfoodfacts(bar_code)
    ])

    // WRITE TO DATABASE
    // database.ref('test/' + bar_code).set(product);

    response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    response.end(JSON.stringify(product))
}

const server = http.createServer(requestHandler)

server.listen(port, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.log('Error occurred', err)
  }

  console.log(`Server is listening on ${port}`)
})
```

Read more about `url` API:

https://nodejs.org/api/url.html